# How we can integrate database with windows 7 phone gap?

Tags: cordova

I am new to windows 7 phonegap. i want to store and retrieve data using native application. i dont know how to store and display the retrieved data from native to phonegap(HTML)page.

can anyone pls guide me how to access sqlite with phonegap.?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite in phonegap/cordova is not supported on Windows Phone 7 unfortunately.
I haven't found any ways around this yet

Comment: How we can store the data in phonegap If SQLite in phonegap/cordova is not supported on Windows Phone 7.

Comment: Does Sqlite support windows phone 8?

Answer (score -2):

You need to use a web database for storing and retrieving data in a Phonegap application.

Here is one example of that database:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Contact Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    // Populate the database
    function populateDB(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
      tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
      tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }
    // Query the database
    function queryDB(tx) {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM DEMO', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
    }
    // Query the success callback
    function querySuccess(tx, results) {
      var len = results.rows.length;
      console.log("DEMO table: " + len + " rows found.");
      for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
        console.log("Row = " + i + " ID = " + results.rows.item(i).id + " Data =  " + results.rows.item(i).data);
      }
    }
    // Transaction error callback
    function errorCB(err) {
      console.log("Error processing SQL: "+err.code);
    }
    // Transaction success callback
    function successCB() {
      var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
      db.transaction(queryDB, errorCB);
    }
    // PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
      var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "PhoneGap Demo", 200000);
      db.transaction(populateDB, errorCB, successCB);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <p>Database</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And for more information about Phonegap database tutorials look up this link: [PHONEGAP DATABASE TUTORIAL](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html). A complete guide is given there.

Best of luck.

Aamirkhan I.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,How can i debug windows 7 application i am using microsoft visual studio?

Comment: To Get Started For Windows7 Phonegap u can see this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/guide_getting-started_windows-phone_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Windows%20Phone

Comment: if this question help full to u than mark it as accepted so that other can take help from this issue....

Comment: But it isn't supported with windows 7 phone gap.when i run it directly with chrome browser it works.How can i make it compatible with windows 7 phone gap.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Database API is not supported on PhoneGap for Windows Phones